# Use Mandrill on Heroku without the addon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, mandrill

Heroku addon for mandrill is getting shutdown, but we'd still like to use mandrill with heroku. So the question is:

Is it possible to still use mandrill with heroku without the heroku addon for it? Can we just point rails mailer at mandrill smtp?

Comment: Why are you so set on Mandrill?  There are other services that will do the same thing with less side effects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use the Mandrill addon.  Just configure ActionMailer in config/environments/production.rb (or whichever environment you are using on Heroku).

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'example.com' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: 'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
  port: 587,
  domain: 'example.com',
  user_name: ENV['MANDRILL_USERNAME'],
  password: ENV['MANDRILL_PASSWORD']
}
```

Change `example.com` to your domain name.

Then run `heroku config:add MANDRILL_USER=yourmandrillusername` and `heroku config:add MANDRILL_PASSWORD=yourmandrillpassword`. Now commit your changes to git and push them to heroku.